# Ordenar diccionarios con elementos asociados por clave

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

tengo que resolver este ejercicio, le he dado mil vueltas pero no termino de encontrar la solución para asociar los valores y ordenarlos, quería saber si me pueden dar una mano.

```
def OrdenarDiccionario(diccionario_par, clave, descendente=True):

'''
Esta función recibe como parámetro un diccionario, cuyas listas de valores tienen el 
mismo tamaño y sus elementos enésimos están asociados. Y otros dos parámetros que 
indican la clave por la cual debe ordenarse y si es descendente o ascendente.

La función debe devolver el diccionario ordenado, teniendo en cuenta de no perder la
relación entre los elementos enésimos.

Recibe tres argumentos:
diccionario:    Diccionario a ordenar.
clave:          Clave del diccionario recibido, por la cual ordenar.
descendente:    Un valor booleano, que al ser verdadero indica ordenamiento ascendente y descendente si es falso. 
                Debe tratarse de un parámetro por defecto en True.

Si el parámetro diccionario no es un tipo de dato diccionario ó el 
parámetro clave no se encuentra dentro de las claves del diccionario, debe devolver nulo.

Ej:
dicc = {'clave1':['c','a','b'],
        'clave2':['casa','auto','barco'],
        'clave3':[1,2,3]}
OrdenarDiccionario(dicc, 'clave1')          debe retornar {'clave1':['a','b','c'],
                                                        'clave2':['auto','barco','casa'],
                                                        'clave3':[2,3,1]}
OrdenarDiccionario(dicc, 'clave3', False)   debe retornar {'clave1':['b','a','c'],
                                                        'clave2':['barco','auto','casa'],
                                                        'clave3':[3,2,1]}
'''
```

Esto de aqui es lo que he logrado pero solo ordena la primera fila, no están asociadas las otras y tampoco encuentro como ordenar las otras.

```
dicc = {'clave1':['c','a','b'],
            'clave2':['casa','auto','barco'],
            'clave3':[1,2,3]}

ordenado = {k: sorted(v) for k, v in dicc.items()}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola estimado @Aledquintero, has intentado algo por tu cuenta?? Más aya del análisis previo, deberías mostrar algo de TU avance y ver qué error estás teniendo en lugar de hacerte la tarea !

Comment: Perdón si se mal entendió, estoy preguntando por donde deberia apuntar, o si hay algun metodo que pueda servir. No deseo el codigo resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que no puedes aplicar un `sorted()` así por así a una lista porque no sabrás qué posición tenían los elementos antes de ser ordenados. Eso quiere decir que tendrás que ordenar manteniendo una referencia de los índices iniciales y luego verificar hacia dónde se han movido.

Observar lo siguiente en la línea de comandos:

```py
>>> a = ['verde', 'rojo', 'azul'] # lista 1 (se usará para ordenar)
>>> b = [8, 3, 9] # lista 2 (lista secundaria)
>>> sorted(a)
['azul', 'rojo', 'verde'] # No se donde estaban inicialmente
>>> # Aqui podría ser de ayuda enumerate()
>>> list(enumerate(a))
[(0, 'verde'), (1, 'rojo'), (2, 'azul')] # [(idx0, val0), (idx1, val1), ...]
```

Sin embargo, es más conveniente tener el valor del índice de segundo para que `sorted()` pueda ordenar la lista automáticamente usando como referencia el primer elemento de cada tupla:

```py
>>> vk = [(v, k) for k, v in enumerate(a)]
>>> vk
[('verde', 0), ('rojo', 1), ('azul', 2)] # [(val0, idx0), (val1, idx1), ...]
>>> sorted(vk)
[('azul', 2), ('rojo', 1), ('verde', 0)]
>>> # Ahora se puede recorrer cada indice y aplicarselo a cada una de las listas
>>> # para mantener la consistencia
>>> sorted_vk = sorted(vk)
>>> [a[idx] for _, idx in sorted_vk]
['azul', 'rojo', 'verde']
>>> [b[idx] for _, idx in sorted_vk]
[9, 3, 8]
```

Listo, ahora solo es aplicar el mismo indexado a todos los elementos del diccionario. Traduciendo todo el concepto en código, quedaría:

```py
def OrdenarDiccionario(dicc, clave, descendente=False):
    vk = [(v, k) for k, v in enumerate(dicc[clave])]
    sorted_vk = sorted(vk, reverse=descendente)
    new_dicc = {}
    for k,v in dicc.items():
        new_dicc[k] = [v[idx] for _, idx in sorted_vk]
    return new_dicc
```

**[*]** Cambié el argumento de la función a `descendente=True`, a `False`. O sea, le tienes que mandar `True` en la llamada a la función para que lo haga en orden inverso.